# Getting count with orderByChild()

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the notification count from the Notifications child. There's another child which has a random key (which I don't know), and within that has a `userKey` value.

I'm wanting to use `orderByChild("userKey")` and get all of the notifications, but not sure how to do this. I've tried looking for a solution, but I can't find one.

[image]

I've tried this but it's not working:

```
db.child("Notifications").orderByChild("userKey").equalTo(intent.getStringExtra("key")).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                indicator.setText(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: you want to know how many children the notification node has?

Comment: Yes, but the ones that have a specific userKey. The problem is that I don't know what the random key is for the notification key.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution will work whenever a new notification is added to the node. If you want to read the notifications for the first time you should use a SingleValueEventListener

```
db.child("Notifications").orderByChild("userKey").equalTo(intent.getStringExtra("key")).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
         indicator.setText(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()));
      }
      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {        
      }
    });
```

Comment: Yeah I know how to read it for the first time, but this isn't what I'm looking for

Comment: Your code seem quite all right, why do you say it doesn't work?

Comment: Because I need to update a text view with the count every time a notification has been added.

Answer (score 0):

- One way is to change the structure of your 'Notifications' Node Structure from

Notifications > Rand_Key > (Data + User_key)

to

Notifications > User_key > Rand_key > (Data)

- In case you need to keep updating the notification count, you can write a Node.js Handler using Firebase Cloud Functions or your own node server, where you can listen to the 'Notifications' onChild added, and update the data wherever it needs to be. If you want to experiment, try cloud functions and remember it is still in beta. 
  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events